# NSURLSession Upload File To Server Swift

Tags: swift, ftp, nsurlsession

I'm creating a Internet Speed testing app and can't seem to get it right to upload the zip file to the ftp server. It is an open server. I want to be able to upload the file and show the progress.

The `func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64)` isn't working.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class Upload: UIViewController, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate {

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/upload")!
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("2MB", ofType: "zip")

    func Test() {
        let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!

        let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
        request.timeoutInterval = 10.0
        request.HTTPBody = data

        let session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        let task: NSURLSessionUploadTask = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: data)

        task.resume()
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {
        print("\(totalBytesSent)/\(totalBytesExpectedToSend)")
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        print(error)
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow)
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the documentation properly. If you look at the documentation for this method,

```
   func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
```

> This method is optional unless you need to support the (relatively
>   obscure) multipart/x-mixed-replace content type. With that content
>   type, the server sends a series of parts, each of which is intended to
>   replace the previous part. The session calls this method at the
>   beginning of each part, and you should then display, discard, or
>   otherwise process the previous part, as appropriate.
>
> If you do not provide this delegate method, the session always allows
>   the task to continue.

Here, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDataDelegate/URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:

You can simply not implement this method or then have to so that it allows further response.

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.Allow)
}
```

Comment: Ok there's no more error but the `didSendBodyData` isn't working?

Comment: Are you sure that the website accepts your data just like that.

Comment: It's an ftp server and I'm not sure, how would I check what data it accepts?

Comment: I think it accepts any file type. Do I need to specify the file type I'm uploading?