# How can upload a zip file into FTP server using swift 3 and iOS 10?

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, xcode8

How can upload a zip file into FTP server using swift 3 and iOS 10? I need to do this in my app to send logs files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to post what you've tried first. The public will not want to type the code for you. Show eventual troubles you are having and you are likely to get good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURLSession Upload File To Server Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128523/nsurlsession-upload-file-to-server-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this framework to upload files to an FTP server: https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/rebekka

With this, you just need to set configuration in AppDelegate (like [this](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/rebekka/blob/master/rebekka-demo/Demo/AppDelegate.swift#L25)) and to upload you use this code:

```
if let URL = NSBundle.main.URL(forResource:"MyLog", withExtension: "zip") {
        let path = "/upload/\(UUID.init().uuidString).zip"
        self.session.upload(URL, path: path) {
            (result, error) -> Void in
            print("Upload file with result:\n\(result), error: \(error)\n\n")
        }
 }
```

Comment: This might be a solution and help to solve the issue, but better try to include  [essential part of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) - the link is supposed to be a reference to the answer.

Comment: @pedrouan Is it okay now?

Comment: Great! If a question has been helpful you can upvote, and if a question answer to your question (and works) you can accept it clicking the ✅