# Upload a file to FTP

Tags: swift, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file with Swift.
I found this (poorly written) tutorial from Apple for Objective-C:

I tried to implement it in Swift, but got stuck on dereferencing the pointer in the callback function:

```
func upload(filepath:String, url:String){
        do {
            let attr:NSDictionary? = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filepath) as NSDictionary;
            if attr == nil { return; }
            let size:UInt64? = attr?.fileSize();
            if size==nil { return; }
            var info = MyStreamInfo(writeStream: CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(nil, CFURLCreateWithString(nil,url as CFString, nil)) as! CFWriteStream,
                                    readStream: CFReadStreamCreateWithFile(nil, CFURLCreateWithString(nil, filepath as CFString, nil)),
                                    /*proxyDict: CFDictionary(), */fileSize: size!, totalBytesWritten: 0, leftOverByteCount: 0, buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bSize));
            var myContext=CFStreamClientContext(version: 0, info: &info, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil);
            //myContext.info = info;
            CFReadStreamOpen(info.readStream);

            CFWriteStreamSetProperty(info.writeStream, CFStreamPropertyKey(kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName), username as CFTypeRef);
            CFWriteStreamSetProperty(info.writeStream, CFStreamPropertyKey(kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword), password as CFTypeRef);
            CFWriteStreamSetProperty(info.writeStream, CFStreamPropertyKey(kCFStreamPropertyFTPProxyHost), hostname as CFTypeRef);
            CFWriteStreamSetProperty(info.writeStream, CFStreamPropertyKey(kCFStreamPropertyFTPProxyPort), port as CFTypeRef);

            CFWriteStreamSetClient(info.writeStream, CFStreamEventType.canAcceptBytes.rawValue, writeCB as! CFWriteStreamClientCallBack, &myContext);


        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print(error);
        }



    }

    func writeCB(stream:CFWriteStream, event:CFStreamEventType, myptr: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
        var info:MyStreamInfo;
        var totalBytesRead:Int32 = 0;
        repeat {
            var bytesRead:Int32 = 0;
            var bytesWritten:Int32 = 0;
            if info.leftOverByteCount>0 {
                bytesRead = Int32(info.leftOverByteCount);
            } else {
                bytesRead = Int32(CFReadStreamRead(info.readStream, info.buffer, bSize));
                if (bytesRead < 0){
                    print("error");
                    return;
                }
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
            bytesWritten = Int32(CFWriteStreamWrite(info.writeStream, info.buffer, CFIndex(bytesRead)));
            if bytesWritten > 0 {
                info.totalBytesWritten += UInt32(bytesWritten);

                if bytesWritten < bytesRead {
                    info.leftOverByteCount = UInt32(bytesRead - bytesWritten);
                    memmove(info.buffer, info.buffer.advanced(by: Int(bytesWritten)), Int(info.leftOverByteCount));
                } else {
                    info.leftOverByteCount = 0;
                }
            } else {
                if bytesWritten < 0  {
                    print("error");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while(CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(info.writeStream));

    }
```

How can I get the MyStreamInfo object out of the pointer?
Am I doing the rest right?
username, password, etc are of course members of my class that I set elsewhere.

Comment: Use [Swiftify](http://objectivec2swift.com) for cases like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can upload a zip file into FTP server using swift 3 and iOS 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982572/how-can-upload-a-zip-file-into-ftp-server-using-swift-3-and-ios-10)

Comment: i don't know how it works in objective-c. as i said, the tutorial is very poorly written and doesn't tell me how i get the info the callback function
the post u linked suggest using additional libraries. i would like to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FilesProvider](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider) library to deal with FTP. It doesn't use deprecated `CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL` API and implements FTP protocol from scratch and provides a high level, `FileManager` like API to deal with FTP/FTPS.

You can see a sample implementation [here](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider/blob/master/Docs/Sample-iOS.swift).